# In a community property state can one spouse sell property they owned before marriage and buy another property and keep still keep it separately owned

Tags: community-property

I've tried finding an answer to this specific question but couldn't. I think in fairness that property or money owned before marriage would still remain the person's own separate property even if they used the money to buy something else... but is that true?

Comment: You are assuming fairness is the determining factor?

Comment: I'm assuming that divorce laws are at least set up to try and be fair... and also since it says that a person keeps their own property that they owned before they got married.

Comment: I hope you get a good answer soon but it is more complicated. There are actions a person can take that turn something that was their individual property into community property. You can google "commingling" for example.

Comment: The law on this point is not identical in all community property regimes. Different places have different rules about it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It just seems to me that it's quite straightforward that if a person had the property before marriage and then sold it and immediately bought another property with that money (and there weren't any other factors like using the other spouse's money etc.) that it should still be their own property...